# Removing trailing NaN from shapefile

Tags: matlab

```
>> roi = shaperead('Gangotri_CopyFeatures.shp');
```

> > % Remove trailing NaN from shapefile
> >     rx = roi.X(1:end-1);

Error using "end"
Incorrect cell or structure reference involving "end".
Most likely cause is a reference to multiple elements of a cell or
structure followed by additional subscript or structure references.

Answer (score 0):

**shaperead** returns a structure so you need to specify the field you are interested in reading.
for example if you want to read the 8th line in roi without the NaN you need the following:

```
roi(8).X(1:end-1)
```